# Convert json format to csv javascript

Tags: javascript, json, csv, format

There are many different versions of conversion but I cannot find this exact one. Can someone help me to convert this JSON to the CSV format below using javascript?

```
{
  "header1": [
    {
      "date": "2022-11-05",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-11-06",
      "value": 2
    }
  ],
  "header2": [
    {
      "date": "2022-11-05",
      "value": 10
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-11-06",
      "value": 20
    }
  ],
  "header3": [
    {
      "date": "2022-11-05",
      "value": 100
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-11-06",
      "value": 300
    }
  ]
}
```

and the csv format...

```
"Date", "header1", "header1", "header1"
"2022-11-05", 1, 10, 100
"2022-11-06", 2, 20, 200
```

I can get the header like so but unsure how to get the data in the proper places/format...

```
let csv = ""
const header = Object.keys(JSONObject);
csv += header.join(",") + "\n";
```

Comment: "Can someone help me" — No, since you haven't told us what problem you are having. You said you've found some examples, but none match this perfectly. That's expected. Stackoverflow is a site designed for programmers. You're supposed to write the program yourself and ask specific questions about specific problems when you get stuck. This question gives the impression you haven't even attempted to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: I have attempted it with json2csv library with no luck. I have also written some code to extract the header but unsure how to get the data in the correct format. Your comment is not helpful.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] of your attempt. Your question is currently better suited to https://www.fiverr.com/

Comment: I added some code for where I am getting stuck.

Comment: I have a solution I developed I will post in a bit. Maybe this will be useful to someone in the future.

Answer (score -1):

```js
    const historicalData = {
      "header1": [
        {
          "date": "2022-11-05",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "date": "2022-11-06",
          "value": 2
        }
      ],
      "header2": [
        {
          "date": "2022-11-05",
          "value": 10
        },
        {
          "date": "2022-11-06",
          "value": 20
        }
      ],
      "header3": [
        {
          "date": "2022-11-05",
          "value": 100
        },
        {
          "date": "2022-11-06",
          "value": 300
        }
      ]
    }

         // csv conversion
          let csv = "Dates,";
          const serialHeader = Object.keys(historicalData);
          csv += serialHeader.join(",") + "\n";
          // get the dates column
          const dates = [];
          historicalData[serialHeader[0]].map((data) => {
            dates.push(data.date);
          });
          for (let j = 0; j < dates.length; j++) {
            const row1 = [];
            row1.push(dates[j]);
            for (let i = 0; i < serialHeader.length; i++) {
              historicalData[serialHeader[i]].map((data) => {
                if (data.date == dates[j]) {
                  row1.push(data.value);
                }
              });
            }
            csv += row1.join(",") + "\n";
          }
          console.log(csv);
```